# How to turn VARBINARY within PeopleSoft into a string?

Tags: sql-server

In PeopleSoft there are string messages that are stored in VARBINARY under the hood.
I would like to convert that data into a string so that I can view it in a data query tool.
Is this possible using SQL and perhaps some built-in SQL Server functions?  I would rather not create a special Java program for just this one field.

Comment: The text of your question says the data type is `MIMEDATALONG`.  The title of your question seems to indicate that it is a `LONG RAW`.  It seems unlikely that PeopleSoft would define a new type since it tends to be pretty database agnostic.  Are the strings longer than 4000 bytes?  If so, is getting just the first 4000 bytes sufficient?

Comment: Thank you.  I found that the actual type is varbinary (xType=165) - this gets me closer!

Comment: `varbinary` isn't an Oracle data type.  I would guess that you mean either `LONG RAW` or `BLOB`.

Comment: ah, I keep forgetting this is actually PeopleSoft running on SQL Server, so the type is in fact VarBinary.

Comment: OK.  Updated the question to indicate that it's a SQL Server question not an Oracle question.

Comment: Did you try `CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), varbinary_column)`? (Or perhaps `NVARCHAR(MAX)`, "string" is pretty ambiguous.

Comment: I have tried permutations of CONVERT and CAST, as in:SELECT TOP 10  CONVERT(varchar(max), MIMEDATALONG ,1)
, master.dbo.fn_varbintohexstr (MIMEDATALONG )
, CAST( MIMEDATALONG as VARCHAR(MAX))
, CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), MIMEDATALONG)
, M.*
FROM PSAPMSGPUBDATA M

Comment: Can you show one of the varbinary values and what you expect as output? Listing a bunch of things you tried doesn't help us figure out where it's going wrong. Also check with PeopleSoft documentation, it's possible the column you're looking at is actually hashed with salt or perhaps even encrypted.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I found out how to translate the data.  It is a compressed string stored as VarBinary.  I needed to use the System.IO.Compression.DeflateStream classDeflate
It would be nice to do this all in SQL, but this at least removes the coding roadblock.

```
... db connection code...
    var query = @"SELECT TOP 10  * FROM PSAPMSGPUBDATA PH WHERE 1=1   AND IBTRANSACTIONID LIKE 'd8d8%'";

    var cmd = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand(query,conn);

    var dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    while (dr.Read())
    {
        dr[5].Dump();
        var stream = dr.GetStream(7);
        var foo = new byte[9000];
        stream.ReadByte();
        stream.ReadByte();
        var output = new System.IO.Compression.DeflateStream(stream, System.IO.Compression.CompressionMode.Decompress);
        var outStream = new MemoryStream();
        var len = (int) stream.Length;
        output.Read(foo,0,9000);
        output.Close();
        var message = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(foo);
        message.Length.Dump();
        message.Dump();
    }
```